# Postman not able to recieve JSON from M to N collection

Tags: mysql, .net-core, postman

I am trying to get an HTTP response from Postman on a Collection that has an M to N relation. The classes for the tables look like this.

**Film Table**

```
public partial class Film
    {
        public Film()
        {
            FilmActor = new HashSet<FilmActor>();
            FilmCategory = new HashSet<FilmCategory>();
            Inventory = new HashSet<Inventory>();
        }

        //Some Properties


        public ICollection<Inventory> Inventory { get; set; }
    }
```

**Linking Table Inventory**

```
public partial class Inventory
    {
        public Inventory()
        {
            Rental = new HashSet<Rental>();
        }

        public int InventoryId { get; set; }
        public short FilmId { get; set; }
        public byte StoreId { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset LastUpdate { get; set; }

        public Film Film { get; set; }
        public Store Store { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Rental> Rental { get; set; }
    }
```

**Store Table**

```
public partial class Store
    {
        public Store()
        {
            Customer = new HashSet<Customer>();
            Inventory = new HashSet<Inventory>();
            Staff = new HashSet<Staff>();
        }

        //More Properties
        public ICollection<Inventory> Inventory { get; set; }

    }
```

I have tried getting the entire collection to display on Postman. The object returned by VS in the "locals" window contains 759 Objects. On the MySql database I have 2270.

This is the query on my Repository

```
return _context.Film
                .Include(x => x.Inventory)
                .Where(x => x.Inventory.Any(c => c.StoreId == storeId))
                .ToList();
```

And I get this error on Postman.

[image]

I also tried applying pagination on the query, because I thought that maybe the server did not support the number of objects being queried. So I only get 10 objects at a time. VS shows me 10 Objects on the "locals" window.

This is my query:

```
 return _context.Film
                .Include(x => x.Inventory)
                .Where(x => x.Inventory.Any(c => c.StoreId == storeId))
                .Skip(filmsResourceParameters.PageSize 
                * (filmsResourceParameters.PageNumber -1))
                .Take(filmsResourceParameters.PageSize)
                .ToList();
```

And I get the same postman error:
[image]

Here are my Postman settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Dto can not have a Collection that contains the linking table, because this would cause a circular dependency that can not be represented in JSON. I can´t explain it any better. If someone can explain it more closely, feel free to do so cause I´d like to learn wtf is going on.